# how to deal with a multiple select list with custom html attributes?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

```
<select class="business_group" multiple="multiple" name="SelectedBusinessGroups">
  <option value="Partners">Partners</option>
  <option value="Press">Press</option>
  <option value="ProductToolbox">Product Toolbox</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="Promotional">Promotional</option>
  <option value="Sponsors">Sponsors</option>
</select>
```

As the attribute named `:selected` mean that option is clicked.
I want to check whether "Promotional" is selected or not from the list of options.
How can I do that?

I tried

```
assert @browser.option(:text => "Promotional").attribute_value("selected").exists? == true
```

but it's not working.

Comment: That is a standard HTML selection list, using the standard element types for such, so you can use the watir methods for selection lists, which includes a way to ask an option if it is selected or not.  See @JustinKo's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of options to check the selected option.

**Using Option#selected?**

Options have a built-in method for telling you if they are selected - see [`Option#selected?`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Option#selected?-instance_method).

```
@browser.option(:text => "Promotional").selected?
#=> true

@browser.option(:text => "Press").selected?
#=> false
```

**Using Select#selected?**

Select lists have a built-in method for check if an options is selected - [`Select#selected?`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Select#selected?-instance_method). Note that this only checks the options based on their text.

```
ddl = @browser.select(:class => 'business_group')

ddl.selected?('Promotional')
#=> true

ddl.selected?('Press')
#=> false
```

**Using Select#selected_options**

The [`Select#selected_options`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir-webdriver/Watir/Select#selected_options-instance_method) method will return a collection of options that are selected. You iterate over this collection to see if the option you want is included. This allows you to check an option by more than its text.

```
selected = @browser.select(:class => 'business_group').selected_options
selected.any?{ |o| o.text == 'Promotional' }
#=> true
```

**Using Element#attribute_value**

The `attribute_value` method will return the attribute value as a string if the attribute exists. If the attribute does not exist, nil is returned.

```
#Compare the attribute value
@browser.option(:text => "Promotional").attribute_value("selected") == 'true'
#=> true

#Compare the attribute value presence
@browser.option(:text => "Promotional").attribute_value("selected").nil? == false
#=> true
```